# FormContront.setValue - reset the html input value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Should `FormContront.setValue` reset the input?

If you look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbgfxv-i3wfbn?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.ts) which is an example straight from Angular Material, there are no less than 3 lines that appear to reset the form value.

```
input.value = '';
...
this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
...
this.fruitCtrl.setValue('');
```

I understood in standard Reactive Forms, `formControl.setValue('')` should be enough to reset the typed string of the HTML `<input>`.

In the example, resetting the native element is also required and I don't follow why.

Comment: you can try the reset() method as well

Comment: the example use a mat-autocomplete to add elements to the Array fruits that is showed as a series of mat-chip. Each time you change the autocomplete you need add to the array and clear the value. For clear the value you only has two options `reset()` or `setValue('')`, choose one of them